# Is my account hacked?

Tags: spam

I accidentally opened up a spam email in my junk folder. However I did not open up the attachment. Is my email and computer ok?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  There simply isn't enough information here to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Opening an email  could be a source of a malicious attack especially when it embeds HTML content (apart from opening an attached file), just as when you visit a website. Such attacks are covered mainly by the name of [drive-by download attacks.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download)

Comment: Ok, is there anything I can do now? The email said something like invoice and please find attached your invoice etc...

Comment: @user204450 classical things: regular analysis for your computer (antivirus if you are on Windows, update your antiviruses, install some security browser plugins such as adblocks for Firefox ...)

Comment: oh ok, well my norton virus protection has not warned me of anything, even when I opened the email, so I think it should be ok?

Comment: @user204450 if your email does not have HTML content, and you did not open the attached file, then you can't be infected/attacked by just opening that email. You know there are dormant viruses in which case your computer can look ok until the virus starts to function under a triggered event (a date, for example). Plus, drive-by download attacks very rarely install a virus directly (they first install spywares, more often)